# How to declare a nullable function Parameter in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

For example:

```
fun f(func: () -> Any?)
```

Parameter func means a function which returns Any? type. But how to make func nullable like:

```
fun f( (func: () -> Any?)? )
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not too far away, I think you just misplaced the parentheses.

Try with:

```
fun f(func: (() -> Any?)?)
```